# pass model to controller with ajax get

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to pass my model to a get method in my controller.

```
<div id="match-object" data-model="@Json.Encode(@Model)"></div>

<script>
    var model = $("#match-object").attr("data-model");
        $.get(myUrl",
              model,
             function(result) {
    $('#result-div').append(result);
});
</script>
```

The above is resulting in the following error:

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Comment: Why? Just pass the ID of the model and GET it again. And the error is because the query string you generating to too long

Comment: What is `model`?

Comment: You always get me on design choices Stephen ;-)  . Once again you're right.